# I can't autoplay vimeo video (mobile)

Tags: jquery, html, dom, vimeo

I'm trying to *autoplay* a video included in a `iframe` on mobile devices.

The app works well, but the user must click on the button inside the iFrame to play the video.

I already tried to use the `"autoplay=1"` parameter in the `iframe` but it didn't work on mobile (on desktop well).

Can you help me?

Comment: This is feature on mobile, to preserve user bandwidth: `Autoplay on most mobile platforms (Android, iOS) gets blocked to avoid poor user experiences - video should only play following a user action. You can usually work around it by triggering the play() on another event (eg the onloaded event)`

Comment: @A.Wolff : Thanks but I must launch it. There were workaround with play() but this is only for HTML5 <video> tag I think!

Comment: Isn't vimeo API expose a play() method? I guess you should be able to find a workaround but unfortunately, i couldn't help you more on this one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @A.Wolff remarks, `autoplay` is disabled by design to preserve bandwidth.

It's, for instance, possible to "trick" iOS into thinking that the user clicked the play button (Google it, if you want to know how).

However, Vimeo would have to implement this since you won't be able to manipulate the contents of an `iframe` from an external source.

Conclusion: You *can't* autoplay an embeded Vimeo video on mobile devices.

(For the curious, I did some digging in the source of the embed player via remote debugging in Safari and wasn't able to find a way to get the video to play without tapping the play button)

Comment: This conclusion is no longer true. You **can** autoplay an embeddded Vimeo video on mobile. The caveat is that the video must be muted for it to work e.g. `<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/{videoId}?autoplay=1&muted=1" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen;" allowfullscreen></iframe>`. The other caveat to bear in mind is that autoplay will **never work** in Safari or Chrome on iOS if low power mode is enabled. I've not tested the low power mode scenario on Android.

Answer (score 1):

https://vimeo.com/help/faq/mobile/mobile-videos#why-cant-i-loop-or-autoplay-my-videos-on-mobile-devices

The link above clearly states that Vimeo won't support mobile autoplay feature. Try using YouTube or BrightCove and I'm certain they do.

Comment: playing video with vimeo wasn't a choice, but a constraint

Answer (score 1):

I tried Vimeo iframe player with iOS 11 and autoplay parameter works well. Only problem is with playing video inline. It seems not possible (at least I couldn't do it).

I tried it also with android (SDK 19 - Android 4.4 and above). Autoplay param doesn't work here for me but I am able to autoplay videos with little workaround:

```
player.loadVideo(videoId).then(function(id)
{
    player.play()
    player.pause()
    setTimeout(function() { player.play() }, 750)
})
```

The player have to be initialized with random video, for example:

```
player = new Vimeo.Player('player', {
    id: 59777392,
    //autoplay: 1 // only for iOS, it is not necessary on Android
})
```

and after `player.ready()` method is fired you can call `loadVideo(videoId)` like I showed above.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my implementaion! I used a library called plyr from [Plyr.io](https://plyr.io)

HTML

```
<div class="plyr__video-embed" id="player">
  <iframe
    src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/videoID?loop=true&amp;autoplay=1&amp;byline=false&amp;portrait=false&amp;title=false&amp;speed=true&amp;transparent=0&amp;gesture=media"
    allowfullscreen
    allowtransparency
    allow="autoplay"
  ></iframe>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const player = new Plyr('#player', {
  autoplay: true,
  controls: false,
  loop: {active: true},
  clickToPlay: false,
    muted: true
});
  document.querySelector('[data-play]').addEventListener('click', () => {
        player.play();                                               
});

  setTimeout(() => {
             document.querySelector('[data-play]').click();
  console.log("play");
             }, 2000)
});
```

It allows playing Vimeo videos automatically on browsers. It works with youtube also
Don't forget to include javascript and css file for plyr library.